# How can I move multiple Pylons Applications into a single Composite Application?

Tags: pylons, composite-application

We have several single Pylon websites running but would like to make these more easily reusable.

There is a concept of a "Composite Application" inside pylons, but there seems to be limited instructions on how to achieve this.

Has anyone done this or is aware of a good tutorial on "How to convert multiple pylons apps into a composite app?" ?

I've tried - perhaps too optimistically - to simply copy an existing app into another app and fiddle with the development.ini file, but this does not seem to work. (I'm getting the error "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: wiki" in that case)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by modifying the WSGI pipeline to dispatch a request to different applications based on request properties (usually URL). The simplest way to modify the pipeline is by PasteDeploy (the package that controls your INI files).

```
[composite:main]
use = egg:Paste#urlmap
/foo = foo
/bar = bar
/ = baz

[app:foo]
use = myapp#main

[app:bar]
use = yourapp#main

[app:baz]
use = myapp#baz
```

This creates a composite application that dispatches to different endpoints based on the URL prefix.